# Mitigating smell from sewage basin

Tags: plumbing, sewage

We recently started having a strong smell coming from around our mechanical room. We initially thought it was related to our septic system and had it pumped. The smell still lingered.

I opened up the sewage basin and didn't see anything abnormal; the pump was working and there didn't appear to be solids in the basin. After receiving my plumbing degree from Google, it looked like the vent pipe was way too long and below the fill line.

I cut about 16" off the vent pipe leaving a few inches under the lid. It's been about 24 hours and the smell has dissipated. Is there anything else that I should examine? Check valve?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: so you solved the problem, any other question

Answer (score 1):

Check that the top end of the vent is still connected to the bottom end.

There is no reason to make the vent go as deep into the sump as it was. it's possible that it originally went to the correct depth but has subsequently dropped.

Answer (score 1):

`After receiving my plumbing degree from Google` LOL

you pass the test

you did it right

The vent line can not vent if it is below the water line

Why was it low, who knows, maybe it slipped so check the clamp.